# Qt Virtual Keyboard по-русски

Tags: qt, клавиатура, virtual

Есть изумительная штука - [Qt Virtual Keyboard](http://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qtvirtualkeyboard-index.html).
Есть вполне пригодный пример в примерах QtCreator. Правда, мне нужен код на qt, а там на qml, но не суть важно - в документации всё хорошо написано и для чистого c++.
В общем, всё работает, но есть одна проблема - язык только английский (а точнее - British English). А мне нужен ещё и русский.

```
CONFIG += lang-ru
CONFIG += lang-ru_RU
CONFIG += lang-all
```

Это всё пробовал - не помогает.

```
console.log("locales available: " + VirtualKeyboardSettings.availableLocales)
```

Это выводит только `en_GB`.

Я в замешательстве.
Обсуждение проблемы есть здесь:
https://forum.qt.io/topic/76802/how-to-enable-virtual-keyboard-languages
и здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40507390/how-to-change-qt-5-7-virtual-keyboard-layout-locale
Но решение не помогло.
Пробовал и на винде, и на маке - всё одно и то же.

Как добавить русскую локализацию, по возможности с примером рабочего кода?

**Update**
Вопрос решился. Подробности по ссылке - [How to change Qt 5.9 virtual keyboard layout/locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46390018/how-to-change-qt-5-9-virtual-keyboard-layout-locale)

Comment: Тут http://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qtvirtualkeyboard-build.html указано как билдить виртуальную клавиатуру, кроме того указано как включить все языки (lang-all в конфиге).

Comment: Где вы искали? Даже по вашей ссылке находится за пару секунд - `CONFIG += lang-ru_RU`. Попробуйте.

Comment: Я специально указал эту ссылку. К сожалению, вариант с CONFIG+=lang-ru_RU у меня не работает. Пробовал добавлять и в про файле, и в параметр qmake.

Comment: Есть пример как запустить виртуальную клавиатуру на c++?